# php generate html element

Tags: php

how to echo this line

```
<td><input name="name" type="text" class="inputs" id="user" value="<? echo $form->value("name"); ?>"/></td>
```

doesnot works

```
echo "<td><input name='name' type='text' class='inputs' id='user' value='<? echo $form->value(\"name\"); ?>'/></td>";
```

and also not working

```
echo "<td><input name='name' type='text' class='inputs' id='user' value='" . htmlspecialchars("<? echo $form->value(\"name\"); ?>").";
```

textbox value should be empyt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want print value of `$form->value("name")`?

I yes use:

```
echo '<td><input name="name" type="text" class="inputs" id="user" value="'.$form->value("name").'"/></td>';
```

Should result with:

```
<td><input name="name" type="text" class="inputs" id="user" value="VAL"/></td>
```

If return value of `$form->value('name')` is `VAL`

If not:

```
echo '<td><input name="name" type="text" class="inputs" id="user" value="<?php echo $form->value("name")"/></td>';
```

Which should result with:

```
<td><input name="name" type="text" class="inputs" id="user" value="<?php echo $form->value('name'); ?>"/></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
echo "<td><input name='name' type='text' class='inputs' id='user' value='" . $form->value('name') . "'/></td>";
```

You can't nest echos like that.

Comment: i have try this before its not working too, i get the following error "Call to a member function value() on a non-object"

Comment: Well that's a different error entirely. That means that `$form` isn't an object. Make sure it is...

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the " to ' in the php block.

```
<td><input name="name" type="text" class="inputs" id="user" value="<? echo $form->value('name'); ?>"/></td>
```

Comment: Ah I see, echo from "inside" another echo. Your question wasn't very clear.